# C Physics engine

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, physics

I am working on a fabric simulator at low level, I have done some work and at this point there are some points where I would appreciate help.

The input of the program is a DRF file. This is a format used in sewing machines to indicate the needles where to move.

The 2D representation is accurate, I parse the DRF info to a polyline, apply tensions and I extrude this in a openGL render.

Now I am trying to achieve the 3D ZAxis physics. I tried two methods:

1) Asuming information

First method is based on constrains about the process of  manufacturing:
we only take care of the knots where a set of yarns interact and comupte z separation in this crucial points. The result is regular: good in a lot of cases but with a lot of botched jobs in order to avoid causistincs where this is not a good assumtion (for example, doing beziers, collisions in zones between this crucial points). We desist on this alternative when we saw there was a lot os causistic we would have to hardcode,probably  creating aditional gliche.

2) Custom 2D Engine

The second attempt is to aprox the yarns with box colliders 2D, check collisions with a grid, and compute new Z in funcion of this. This is by far more expensive, but leads to a better results. Although, there is some problems:

- The accuracy of box colliders over the yarn is not absolute ( there are ways to solve this but it would be great to read some alternatives)
- There is not iterative process:

  First we compute collisions pairwise, and add to each collider a list of colliding colliders. Then, we arrange this list and separate the Z axis in function of yarn's radius with center 0.The last step is to smooth the results from discrete z to a beziers or smoothing filters. This leads to another glitches.
  If I extend this recomputation to all the collisions of the current collisions, I get weird results because z changes are bad propagated( maybe I am not doing good this point)
- Some colliders are recomputed wrong ( first computed yarns have more posibilites to be altered for the last ones, leading on gliches)

This is the result for the secdond approach ( without recompute z's on smoothing step):
[image: 3D]

And some of the glicthes (mainly in the first yarns computed:

[image]

This is the collisions engine:

[image]

Details of bad aproximated curves:
[image]

At this point I have some questions:

- Can I fix this glitches (or a great part at least)?
  Glitches about bad aproximation and glitches for z recomputation
- A 3D engine like ODE could do the job in a reasonable time?

If you need some specific code don't hestiate on ask for it.

EDIT: Ok, let's narrow the thing.

Yesterday I tried some open source engines without achieving good results.
500 collisions with joints are crashing the simulation. so I discard it.

My problem:

A: How I generate the yarns: 
I have a set of points and I trace beziers between them.

```
 CUBIC_BEZIER(p1x,p1y,p1z,p2x,p2y,p2z,p3x,p3y,p3z,p4x,p4y,p4z, npunts);
```

For each pair of points I add a collider:

```
         p1.x = *(puntlinaux + k*NUMCOMP);      
         p1.y = *(puntlinaux + k*NUMCOMP + 1);

         p2.x = *(puntlinaux + k*NUMCOMP + 4);
         p2.y = *(puntlinaux + k*NUMCOMP + 5);

         *bc = getCollider(&p1,&p2,x,y,z, radi_mm_fil , pbar->numbar);
```

where

```
BoxCollider2D  getCollider(punt_st* p1, punt_st* p2, float *x, float *y, float *z, float radiFil,int numbar){

      BoxCollider2D bc;
      bc.numBar = numbar;

      int i;

      for(i = 0; i < MAX_COLLIDERS; i++) {
         bc.collisions[i] = NULL;
      }

      bc.isColliding = 0;
      bc.nCollisions = 0;
      bc.nextCollider = NULL;
      bc.lastCollider = NULL;
      bc.isProcessed = 0;

      punt_st center;
      p1->x = p1->x;
      p2->x = p2->x; 
      float distance = distancePunts_st(p1,p2);      
      bc.angle = atan2((p2->y - p1->y),(p2->x-p1->x)); 
      //bc.angle = 0;
      //DEBUG("getCollider\n");
      //DEBUG("angle: %f, radiFil: %f\n", bc.angle*360/(2*3.141592), radiFil);
      //DEBUG("Point: pre [%f,%f] post:[%f,%f]\n", p1->x, p1->y, p2->x, p2->y);

      p1->y = p1->y;
      p2->y = p2->y;
      bc.r.min = *p1;
      bc.r.max = *p2;
      center = getCenterRect(bc.r);

      bc.r.max.x = (center.x - distance/2);
      bc.r.max.y = (center.y + radiFil) - 0.001f;

      bc.r.min.x = (center.x + distance/2);
      bc.r.min.y = (center.y - radiFil) + 0.001f;

      bc.xIni= x;
      bc.yIni= y;
      bc.zIni= z;

      return bc;
}
```

Then I add the collider to a grid to reduce complexity on comparisons
  and check the collisions with Separated Axis Theorem

```
DEBUG("calc_sapo: checking collisions\n"); 
    checkCollisions();
```

After that, I resolve the collisions leading on a discrete z aproximation.

```
DEBUG("calc_sapo: solving collisions\n");
    resolveCollisions();
```

And then I apply a smooth function. This is the point where I am lost.
        DEBUG("smoothing yarns\n");
        smoothYarns();

To keep it simple, let's assume smoothYarns() does a simple mean value with the last and next z value:

for each collider of each yarn:

```
         float aux = (*bc->zIni + *(bc-1)->zIni + *nextBC->zIni)/3;
         float diff = aux - *bc->zIni; 
         *bc->zIni = aux;
```

Then we have to update all the colliders in contact with this recomputed collider:

```
void updateCollider(BoxCollider2D *bc, float diff){


    int i ;

    for(i = 0; i < bc->nCollisions; i++){

        *bc->collisions[i]->zIni += diff;


    }

}
```

This last step is messing up all the simulation because z's are accumulating theirselves ...

[image]

I want to know why this does not tend to converge as I expected and possible solutions for this problem.

EDIT2:

This is the algorithm that detects collisions:

1. For each collider in the grid position

   - Compare with others in the grid
   - if colliding: add the colliding collider to the current collider
2. For each yarn:

   - Go trhough all the colliders (linked list)

     - For each collider from a yarn:
     - Bubble sort collision yarns in function of their z order
     - Compute z based on yarns radius (centered on 0)

```
 float computeZ(BoxCollider2D *array[], int nYarns, BoxCollider2D *bc){
        int i, antBar;
        float radiConflicte = 0;
        float zMainYarn;
        finger_st *pfin;
        antBar = -1;
        for(i = 0; i<nYarns; i++){
            if(pfin != array[i]->pfin){      
              float radiFil = getRadiFromBC2D(*array[i]); // veure getCollider
              radiConflicte += radiFil;
              pfin = array[i]->pfin;      
            }     
        }
        antBar = -1;
        pfin = NULL;
        for(i = 0; i<nYarns; i++){
            float radiFil = getRadiFromBC2D(*array[i]); // veure getCollider  
            if(pfin != array[i]->pfin){  
                radiConflicte -= radiFil;
                *(array[i]->zIni) =  radiConflicte;
                if(array[i] == bc) zMainYarn = *(array[i]->zIni);
                radiConflicte -= radiFil;
                pfin = array[i]->pfin; 
            } 
            else *(array[i]->zIni) = *(array[i-1]->zIni);
        }
```

This leads in a approach where the last yarns processed can alter the firsts  ones, and, in last instance, to glitches.

How I can avoid that?

Thanks a lot!